# Propose that the [ibooks] tag is renamed to [apple-books]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

Apple dropped the `iBooks` branding for just `Books` in iOS 12 / Mojave in 2018. We should follow suit with the tag name at this point: I’d suggest [apple-books] but of course am open to suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for this useful suggestion!

I migrated all existing questions (a total of 33 questions at the time of migration) from [ibooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) to the new [apple-books](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-books) tag.

Subsequently I introduced a tag synonym accordingly [ibooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) -> [apple-books](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-books)